# Changing location of virtual drive for Google Drive

Tags: windows, google-drive-file-stream

I've asked several questions about Google Drive in the past, and one of them was trying to figure out where my virtual drive was as it wasn't showing up in diskmgr but still showing in Explorer. I figured out that this virtual drive was, in fact, a virtual drive, and hence not actually a physical partitioning of my disk. However, this left another problem as I kept getting limited to around 8-12gb of space that I could place files in so they could be automatically uploaded to my drive. At the time I figured this was a Google Drive restriction, but as I had tried to upload close to that limit, I'd gotten an "Out of space" notification for my main C:// 128GB SSD. It then clicked in my head that this virtual drive was not stored on my D:// drive but yet on C://, and since it is only 128GB and only had about 10gb left, this caused it to limit the available space on the virtual drive. In Google Drive settings all they allow me to customize is the letter for the virtual drive. So is there any way to change the **ACTUAL** location of the Google virtual drive?

Comment: Please read carefully [Configure Google Drive for desktop](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7644837?hl=en) (official help article)

Comment: thank you very much, was having lots of trouble finding this as my googling skills leave something to be desired. do you mind leaving an answer with the specific methods of doing this, such as using DefaultMountPoint in regedit? I will make sure to accept!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm glad that you found the help article helpful. P.S. regedit is for Windows in MacOS the settings are on plist file; I haven't modified yet a plist file and I don't know what is the proper way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

ContentCachePath and DefaultMountPoint

These are the two regedit strings i created in the User only    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\DriveFS

this moved the data from my main boot drive to an auxiliary drive.